# what it the JPQL jpa (@Query) for update column with binary operator mysql query?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

**SQL Query:**

```
update de_meta set service_lines = service_lines | 5 where de_id = 20;
```

This works fine from SQL console.

**JPA Query:**

```
@Modifying
@Query("update DeMetaEntity set serviceLines = serviceLines | ?2 where deId = ?1")
void addDeServiceLineMap(Integer deId, int serviceLine);
```

This JPA query throws error because | (bitwise OR) is not valid in JPQL. 
Is there any way to write equivalent JPQL for given SQL query?

I don't want to use criteria queries. As I use this at JAVA INTERFACE.

Comment: Specify it as a native query. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html

Comment: I want to use it as Single update query without performing select first. Not sure how are you proposing?

Comment: ?????? @Query("update DeMetaEntity set serviceLines = serviceLines | ?2 where deId = ?1", **nativeQuery = true**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a native query as Alan suggested:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update de_meta set service_lines = service_lines | ?2 where de_id = ?1", nativeQuery=true)
void addDeServiceLineMap(Integer deId, int serviceLine);
```

The switch nativeQuery=true will execute the SQL query as it is.

Comment: Okay, what problem are you trying to solve? Why are you writing a query rather rmodifying the in-memory-entity and persisting it?

Comment: I don't want to read the service_line, change and persist. Rather I want to perform binary operation on the service_lines column directly without reading the value.